# What kind of statistics models can use binary data to predict binary data?

Tags: regression, modeling, model, binary-data

I want to construct probability models with the following structure:

$$\Bbb P(Y=1) = f(X_1,...,X_n)$$
where $Y \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ and $\forall i, X_i \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$

My data doesn't have a particular distribution that I know of a priori.

At the moment, my sample size is 30 observations. According to what I read, one needs roughly minimum 30 observations per parameter to be estimated for logit/probit. So that would mean minimum 900 observations, which isn't happening. I would say 75 would probably be the largest I can get and 100 absolute max. This is medical data collected over time, so I can't just go get it. It's collected on a schedule more or less. Future tests are planned. But as I said, tops 75-100 if that. I have about 30 variables. But I don't need all of them for prediction, many of them I expect to be correlated.

I don't think Logit and Probit models are appropriate because I don't have any numerical variables. I have googled quite a bit and can't find any models taht involve mapping binary variables onto a probability of a binary variable.

## My Question

Do any methods exist for this purpose? If logit/probit is appropriate, can someone explain why and what particular issues my data set will face (see link in comments)?

Comment: Logistic and probit are totally appropriate.  Not sure why you think you don't have numeric variables, $0$ and $1$ are numbers.

Comment: I agree with Matthew, logit and probit would be appropriate for your data.  Just code one of the outcomes as 0 and the other as 1

Comment: What restrictions must there be on the relationships between the variables? For MLR we have the Gauss Markov assumptions. What assumptions must be satisfied for logistic and probit to be applicable?

Comment: I think the OP is being misunderstood.  He intends to have Y and the X_i all binary with 0 and 1 as a coding.

Comment: @MichaelChernick correct

Comment: @Michael I don't see *anything* here that invalidates the comments by Matthew Drury and Marquis de Carabas, nor anything that suggests either of them failed to understand the question in any way. Their comments are spot on and are suitable answers the question -- they probably should be posted as such. Of course there are other choices than the commonly used logit and probit models for this case, but those are typically the first things that would be considered.

Comment: Two points: (1) my sample size is small. I updated the question to reflect that. (2) if logit and probit models are appropriate, I don't know how to do the diagnostics for binary data. Any know of a resource that explains how to do this? All the assumption diagnostics I have done in the past have been on numerical data

Comment: @Glen_b I get your point.  The question deal with an unspecified form for the function f.  I think that opens this up for lots of possibilities.  Small sample size is going to be issue in modeling with any approach.

Comment: An important factor is how many variables $X_i$ there are? In the extreme case that there is only one, you essentially just have four pieces of information: a 2x2 table $(X,Y)$, and a completely general probability model would just fit a different prediction for the two values of $X$ (with about 15 pieces of information each, maybe). Of course, the number of tables in the cell grows exponentially with the number of variables $X$ -- so just how many are there?

Comment: With logistic regression there are n + 1 parameters to estimate and we don't know how the number of Xi s compare to the sample size.

Comment: @Michael -- apologies if I am misunderstanding you; however, with all $X$-variables binary, any $f$ will be representable as linear in a full-factorial model (i.e. with all interactions present) within a logit or probit framework. Of course, one needs to focus on what can be estimated, but if $f$ is unknown one looks to simplified relationships (simple in at least some sense, whether by omitting high order terms or by some form of regularization - like LASSO perhaps - to make the model estimable)

Comment: Yep, logit/probit will work.  The problems that will occur from multicollinearity (correlation among explanatory variables) and not a large sample size will resemble those problem in other glm models.  However, you might also have [quasi complete or complete separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(statistics)).